Derivative of Riemann-Hilbert problem
Let $L$ be a line segment on the real axis of the complex plane, and $F(z)$ is a segmentally analytic function with the following jump condition,
$$
F(t^+) - F(t^-)=f(t),\quad \text{on}\; L(t) \tag{1}.
$$
where $F(t^+)$ and $F(t^-)$ are the limits of $F(t)$ from the left and right sides of $L$, and $f(t)$ is a function that satisfy the Hölder conditions on $L$.
$F(z)$ is given by the Plemelj formula as
$$
F(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L{\frac{f(t)}{t-z}\:dt} \tag{2}.
$$

There are two approaches to find the derivative of $F(z)$ in the direction of $L$, namely, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}$, where $z=x_1+ix_2$:

Differentiate $F(z)$ in (2) with respect to $x_1$.

$$
\frac{\partial F(z)}{\partial x_1} = F'(z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x_1} = F'(z)
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L{\frac{f(t)}{(t-z)^2}\:dt} \tag{3}.
$$

Differentiate the jump condition (1) and solve for $F'(z)$ with Plemelj formula. With $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial }{\partial t}$,

$$
F'(t^+) - F'(t^-)=f'(t),\quad \text{on}\; L(t). \tag{4}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial F(z)}{\partial x_1} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L{\frac{f'(t)}{t-z}\:dt}
 =\left.-\frac{f(t)}{t-z}\right|_{t_0}^{t_1} + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_L{\frac{f(t)}{(t-z)^2}\:dt}.
\tag{5}
$$
Why does the solution derived with the second approach contains an extra term? What went wrong? If both approaches are correct, how to interpret the extra term here?
